# Mysql : 10 million record in a day, automatic partition or manual partition

Tags: mysql, partition, database-partitioning, bigdata

I have a table whoes structure is like this :

```
user_id              Primary     bigint(20)
date                 Primary     date
country              Primary     varchar(2)
fans                             int(11)
```

This table has 10 millions record incoming everyday.

I need data for at least 6 months. Older data will mostly not be required.

The data will be `1,000,000*180 = 180,000,000` in 6 months.

I am planning to implement partitioning by these 2 ways

1. Automatic partition the table based on date(6 month and older than that).
2. Manual partition by creating a table called `table_archived` and dumping records in it every night by cron.

My queries are :

1. Which of the above method is best and why
2. If I go for options 2 than the archived table will or will not effect the mysql performance?(Considering the _archived table will not be accessed.)
3. Is there a better way to handle this issue.

Comment: how much are you getting paid for this huh? ;)

Comment: @sourRaspberri Answer this and I will give you half.. ;)

Comment: @sourRaspberri: Not allowed to ask confidential information ;) btw do you have any other solution depending on it ?